# PyQT QTableWidget extremely slow

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtablewidget

this is the code I use to fill a table drawn in QT Designer.
Designed to be universal for any table, it works fine, but...
When I try to show a datasat containing 18 columns and ~12000 rows, it just freezes for 30 seconds or more.
So, what I am doing wrong and is there way to speed up, keeping the code still suitable for any table?

That's my code:

```
...blablabla...

self.connect(self, SIGNAL("set"), self.real_set)

...blablabla...

def set_table(self, table, data):
    self.emit(SIGNAL('set'), table, data)

def real_set(self, table, data):
    """
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    Assuming data is list of dict and table is a QTableWidget.

    Get first key and get len of contents
    """
    for key in data:
        rows = len(data[key])
        table.setRowCount(rows)
        break

    """
    Forbid resizing(speeds up)
    """
    table.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(QHeaderView.Fixed)
    table.verticalHeader().setResizeMode(QHeaderView.Fixed)
    table.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(False)
    table.verticalHeader().setStretchLastSection(False)

    """
    Set number of columns too
    """
    table.setColumnCount(len(data))
    table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(sorted(data.keys()))

    """
    Now fill data
    """
    for n, key in enumerate(sorted(data.keys())):
        for m, item in enumerate(data[key]):
            newitem = QTableWidgetItem(item)
            table.setItem(m, n, newitem)
```

Comment: ~12000 rows is a pretty large table...

Comment: Do you mean to say `QTableWidget` in the title? Because you seem to be using `QTableWidgetItem` in the code... Also, a more complete code would be good, because now there is no idea what the types of `table` or `item` are, for example.

Comment: Try measuring the time it takes to complete individual portions of your code to narrow down the issue. Is it retrieving the data? Is it filling in the table with items?

Comment: @JamesElderfield It's stock market data.

Comment: @hyde Thanks, I fixed and added some comments,

Comment: @cpburnz it's definitely filling the table.

Comment: You can't add all 12000 items at once, because that blocks the event loop for too long time. The technique of the pagination solution given in that one answer is way to go, but instead of pagination by user actions, you could just have a timer with interval 0, and add some suitable number of items (universal solution is to time it at runtime, and stop adding items for that timeout when you have spent, say, 100 ms adding them. and then continue when the timer timeout fires next time). That way Qt event loop can keep running, and GUI works.

Comment: @hyde But it's asychronous app. Does Qt event loop have its own GIL like python itself does?

Comment: @pmus. An 18x12000 table is quite small. It shouldn't take anywhere near 30 seconds to fill that. In my own tests, a 20x15000 table only takes 3-4 seconds to fill. You need to provide a **complete** example that shows the performance problem, so other people can try to reproduce it.

Comment: @pmus Qt GUI is single-threaded (you can have other threads, but they can't *directly* touch the GUI). So while you have your own method executing in the GUI thread, nothing else happens in the GUI. When your own method returns, it returns to Qt event loop. So there is no need for GIL as such, that's not what blocks the event loop, it is just that you are *in* the event loop, which is calling your method, and won't do anything until your method returns.

Comment: @ekhumoro I'd hazard a guess, that it has to do with sorting. Anyway, a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) seems to be necessary here, indeed.

Comment: @hyde. My tests used a randomized data-set, and the results include a `sortByColumn` after the table has been populated. There must be some other code that the OP is not showing that is the cause of the slow down.

Comment: @ekhumoro Yes, I've double checked my data structure and this code:
' result.append(str(value).decode('utf-8'))' on returning data seems to be slowing down my data table as hell. So, some part of problem is sovled thanks to you all guys.

I should do all the encode/decode things on adding data, not when I'm representing it! It's now about 5 times faster, but still slow.

Comment: @pmus. You can get much better performance if you use a `QTableView` with a custom model which pulls the values directly from your data structure. The main bottleneck is creating all those instances of `QTableWidgetItem`. In my tests, a 20x15000 table only takes a fraction of a second to fill when using a custom model.

Comment: @ekhumoro May I see your test to check it out? ;)

Comment: @pmus. Sure - please see my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here a test script which compares a few ways of populating a table.

The custom model is much faster, because it does not have to create all the items up front - but note that it is a very basic implementation, so does not implement sorting, editing, etc. (See [Model/View Programming](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html) for more details).

```
from random import shuffle
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._data = data

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self._data)

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self._data[0]) if self.rowCount() else 0

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            row = index.row()
            if 0 <= row < self.rowCount():
                column = index.column()
                if 0 <= column < self.columnCount():
                    return self._data[row][column]

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.table = QtGui.QTableView(self)
        self.tablewidget = QtGui.QTableWidget(self)
        self.tablewidget.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.button1 = QtGui.QPushButton('Custom Model', self)
        self.button1.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.populateTable('custom'))
        self.button2 = QtGui.QPushButton('StandardItem Model', self)
        self.button2.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.populateTable('standard'))
        self.button3 = QtGui.QPushButton('TableWidget', self)
        self.button3.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.populateTable('widget'))
        self.spinbox = QtGui.QSpinBox(self)
        self.spinbox.setRange(15000, 1000000)
        self.spinbox.setSingleStep(10000)
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.table, 0, 0, 1, 4)
        layout.addWidget(self.tablewidget, 1, 0, 1, 4)
        layout.addWidget(self.button1, 2, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.button2, 2, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.button3, 2, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.spinbox, 2, 3)
        self._data = []

    def populateTable(self, mode):
        if mode == 'widget':
            self.tablewidget.clear()
            self.tablewidget.setRowCount(self.spinbox.value())
            self.tablewidget.setColumnCount(20)
        else:
            model = self.table.model()
            if model is not None:
                self.table.setModel(None)
                model.deleteLater()
        if len(self._data) != self.spinbox.value():
            del self._data[:]
            rows = list(range(self.spinbox.value()))
            shuffle(rows)
            for row in rows:
                items = []
                for column in range(20):
                    items.append('(%d, %d)' % (row, column))
                self._data.append(items)
        timer = QtCore.QElapsedTimer()
        timer.start()
        if mode == 'widget':
            self.tablewidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
            for row, items in enumerate(self._data):
                for column, text in enumerate(items):
                    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(text)
                    self.tablewidget.setItem(row, column, item)
            self.tablewidget.sortByColumn(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        else:
            self.table.setSortingEnabled(False)
            if mode == 'custom':
                model = TableModel(self._data, self.table)
            elif mode == 'standard':
                model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self.table)
                for row in self._data:
                    items = []
                    for column in row:
                        items.append(QtGui.QStandardItem(column))
                    model.appendRow(items)
            self.table.setModel(model)
            self.table.setSortingEnabled(True)
            self.table.sortByColumn(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        print('%s: %.3g seconds' % (mode, timer.elapsed() / 1000))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 50, 1200, 800)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I must admit you're a mighty coder. It will take for me some time to review and analyze your script!

Answer (score 5):

In GUI applications one comes across a situation where there is a need
to display a lot of items in a tabular or list format (for example
displaying large number of rows in a table). One way to increase the
GUI responsiveness is to load a few items when the screen is displayed
and defer loading of rest of the items based on user action. Qt
provides a solution to address this requirement of loading the data on
demand.

You can find the implementation of this technique called pagination in this [link](https://sateeshkumarb.wordpress.com/2012/04/01/paginated-display-of-table-data-in-pyqt/)

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: It's a good point, but will not suit my case exactly because of needs to show the table at once.

Comment: @pmus You need a mighty big display if you are going to show all that data at once ;)

Comment: @hyde No, just when I see the table, I'd need to sort it by values. So page-by-page loading isn't an option.

Comment: @pmus You can sort the data pre-pagination.

Comment: @pmus The code in the question looks like it doesn't matter in which order you add the items... Or is it that it gets re-sorted every time you add a new item, in other words getting sorted 12000 times? No wonder it is slow, if that is the case! :).

Comment: @hyde In code, I sort only columns dict (which takes no time). But when the table is displayed, I can view and sort items, of course.