# Update QTableWidget rows with each iteration of loop

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qtablewidget

**I want to simultaneously update the QTableWidget with each iteration of loop as a row is inserted in the table**

I need that because if I wait for for changes to show up after the loop ends it takes almost forever to do that because there are hundreds of rows are being inserted into the table so I want to see the rows in the table being inserted with each iteration of the loop.

**Here is the table definition**

```
    self.tableResults = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self)
    self.tableResults.setGeometry(10, 10, 580, 300)
    self.tableResults.setColumnCount(7)
    self.tableResults.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Game Number" , "Game Name" , "Date" , "First" , "Second" , "Third" , "Fourth"])
    self.tableResults.setUpdatesEnabled(True)
```

The loop is triggered when a button is pressed and it also freezes the whole GUI

**The definition of the event handler is as follows:**

```
def btnStartClick(self):

    startYear = self.startDatePicker.date().year();
    startMonth = self.startDatePicker.date().month();
    startDay = self.startDatePicker.date().day();
    startDate = date(startYear,startMonth,startDay)

    endYear = self.endDatePicker.date().year();
    endMonth = self.endDatePicker.date().month();
    endDay = self.endDatePicker.date().day();
    endDate = date(endYear,endMonth,endDay)

    delta = endDate - startDate
    gameResults = []
    for i in range(delta.days + 1):
        tdate = startDate + td(days=i)
        resultDate = tdate.strftime("%m/%d/%y")
        results = getResults(resultDate)

        for gameId in results:
            self.tableResults.insertRow(self.tableResults.rowCount())
            gameResult = getGameResult(gameId,date)

            self.tableResults.model().setItem(self.tableResults.rowCount() , 0 , QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(gameResult.gameNumber)))
            self.tableResults.model().setItem(self.tableResults.rowCount() , 1 , QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(gameResult.gameName)))
            self.tableResults.model().setItem(self.tableResults.rowCount() , 2 , QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(gameResult.date)))
            self.tableResults.model().setItem(self.tableResults.rowCount() , 3 , QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(gameResult.first)))
            self.tableResults.model().setItem(self.tableResults.rowCount() , 4 , QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(gameResult.second)))
            self.tableResults.model().setItem(self.tableResults.rowCount() , 5 , QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(gameResult.third)))
            self.tableResults.model().setItem(self.tableResults.rowCount() , 6 , QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(gameResult.fourth)))
            gameResults.append(gameResult)

    print(gameResults)
```

Comment: Is it really needed to update it that often? This won't work fast if you insert each iteration a table. It would be better to update the table only with a bigger count of tables. Maybe it's because of python too. So far I know python is nice for programming but worse for performance.

Comment: It's because there's a stop button also that stops this operation when needed so if stop button is pressed it needs to display the inserted rows.

Comment: @ArthurM. No it doesn't it just takes forever to insert all the rows and displays nothing

Comment: Did I understood that right, all data is at that point available?

Comment: what I am trying to say is that after an Item is set in the table using setItem() method it should display that cell inserted in the GUI while the application is being executed.

Comment: @MehrozIrshad. A custom model will be much, much faster than using `QTableWidget` or `QStandardItemModel`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39088300/984421) for a performance comparison.

Answer (score 1):

## Important information:

With a QTableWidget the solution doesn't work. So here is shown how the code must be changed for speed-up and for using a QTableWidget.

### Explanation

Because you can't add a couple of rows at once with a QTableWidget it's needed to take the QTableView. The important difference here is that you can choose the item model to suit your needs. Here a QStandardItemModel is chosen because it supports the missing function `appendRow(...)`. This is what we want because the paint event is called after a couple of items are inserted and not as before after an item has been inserted or edited.

### Needed code before

```
self.tableResults = QTableView(self);
self.tableResults.setModel(QStandardModel(0, 7, self));
```

#### Additional information:

The QTableView class needs a class which inherits from QAbstractItemModel because this class manages the data. So to use QTableView it's needed to set an item model.

Why QStandardModel?
The QStandardModel class provides more functions which help add multiple items at once.

### Changed Code

```
def btnStartClick(self):

    startYear = self.startDatePicker.date().year();
    startMonth = self.startDatePicker.date().month();
    startDay = self.startDatePicker.date().day();
    startDate = date(startYear,startMonth,startDay)

    endYear = self.endDatePicker.date().year();
    endMonth = self.endDatePicker.date().month();
    endDay = self.endDatePicker.date().day();
    endDate = date(endYear,endMonth,endDay)

    delta = endDate - startDate
    gameResults = []
    for i in range(delta.days + 1):
        tdate = startDate + td(days=i)
        resultDate = tdate.strftime("%m/%d/%y")
        results = getResults(resultDate)
        for gameId in results:
            List row;

            gameResult = getGameResult(gameId,date)
            row.append(QtWidgets.QStandardItem(str(gameResult.gameNumber)))
            row.append(QtWidgets.QStandardItem(str(gameResult.gameName)))
            row.append(QtWidgets.QStandardItem(str(gameResult.date)))
            row.append(QtWidgets.QStandardItem(str(gameResult.first)))
            row.append(QtWidgets.QStandardItem(str(gameResult.second)))
            row.append(QtWidgets.QStandardItem(str(gameResult.third)))
            row.append(QtWidgets.QStandardItem(str(gameResult.fourth)))
            (self.tableResults.model()).appendRow(row); #maybe a cast to this class is needed QStandardItemModel. It's python so I'm not sure
            gameResults.append(gameResult)

    print(gameResults)
```

Comment: @ArtherM I reviewed your solution but it appears in pyqt there's no QList and .append() method available is there any other way to speed up the process..

Comment: I think .appendRow() method is only available for c++ not for python

Comment: I changed the whole answer to correct it and simplify reading.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the `repaint()` method of `QtWidgets.QListView`:

```
self.listView = QtWidgets.QListView()
self.model = QStandardItemModel()
self.listView.setModel(self.model)
for i in range(10):
    item = QStandardItem(QIcon('pdf.png'), "txt string")
    self.model.appendRow(item)
    self.listView.repaint()
    time.sleep(1)
```