# How to move GUI update to another QThread

Tags: python, pyqt, qthread

The code below creates a single `QTableView` window with 10,000 rows.
Every second the view refreshes itself by calling the same `update()` function. Unfortunately this update process makes the entire window lock and slows down the responsiveness of the window noticeably.

I wonder if there is a way to move the call to `update()` function to another Thread so it does not block the main window?

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app=QtGui.QApplication([])
items  = ['item_%04d'%i for i in range(10000)]

def update():
    view.model().sourceModel().clear()

    for i, item in enumerate(items):
        for column_number in range(5):
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(item)
            model.setItem(i, column_number, item)


view = QtGui.QTableView()
model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(len(items), 5)
proxy = QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel()
proxy.setSourceModel(model)
view.setModel(proxy)

timer = QtCore.QTimer()
view.connect(timer, QtCore.SIGNAL("timeout()"), update)
timer.start(1000)

view.show()
app.exec_()
```

## EDITED LATER:

The code below is my attempt to move the `update GUI` process to another thread. But unfortunately the lag is still there even while the update process happens in another thread (logging prints out the thread name):

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import threading, time, logging  
logging.basicConfig(format='%(threadName)s:%(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)

app=QtGui.QApplication([])
items  = ['item_%04d'%i for i in range(10000)]

def worker():   
    while True:
        view.model().sourceModel().clear()
        for i, item in enumerate(items):
            for column_number in range(5):
                item = QtGui.QStandardItem(item)
                model.setItem(i, column_number, item)

        time.sleep(1)       
        logging.info('updaing gui...')

view = QtGui.QTableView()
model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(len(items), 5)
proxy = QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel()
proxy.setSourceModel(model)
view.setModel(proxy)

t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
t.setDaemon(True)
logging.info('starting worker...')
t.start()
view.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: It can not: <<< ***GUI Thread and Worker Thread***

As mentioned, each program has one thread when it is started. This thread is called the "main thread" (also known as the "GUI thread" in Qt applications). ***The Qt GUI must run in this thread. All widgets and several related classes, for example QPixmap, don't work in secondary threads***. A secondary thread is commonly referred to as a "worker thread" because it is used to offload processing work from the main thread.<<< http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/thread-basics.html

Comment: How do we deal with the lagging in the situation like this?

Comment: The delay is due to the enormous amount of information that has to be updated, the only way to eliminate the delay is to update in parts (but I think that is not the solution for you), I can give you another option that does not solve the problem but If it helps the user, this is to place a QProgressbar.

Comment: The bottleneck is that you are creating **all** the items up front, every time you update the table. There is nothing that can be done to speed that up - `QStandardItemModel` is designed for convenience, not efficiency. You will have to use a custom model if you want better performance - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39088300/984421).