# Viewing a sub region of a Qtableview

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview, qstandarditemmodel

I have a qtableview that allows the users to edit values in the cells and update the underlying model.   That works fine for small models (row*column size of 100 to 500) but gets unmanageable at > 1000 and some of my models can get huge (>20000).  I thought of allowing the user to see sub regions of the model and to page around the model in the tableview.   But I see no methods that would allow me to do this, unless I build my own.   Am I missing it?  Would hiding and showing large section of the model be the best method?  (I was thinking of 4 buttons that would page data (model) up/down and left right)

Comment: up, down, left, right ?? the models are not graphics, if you are going to handle a lot of data and have efficiency problems do not use QStandardItemModel, create your own model. the information display part is handled by QTableView, it is optimized to show that kind of information. what do you want to do?

Comment: To be clear - the general function of QTableView and QStandardItemModel work fine.   What I am looking for is say to ONLY look at N number of rows of data starting at a offset of the base row X, and M number of columns of data starting at  a offset from the base column Y.

Comment: okay, now I understand, you want to show a submodel. :D

Comment: PyQt4 or PyQt5?

Comment: PyQt5 is what I use these days.

Comment: @TimCarnahan. Use a custom model. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39088300/984421) for a basic comparison (it uses pyqt4/qtablewidget, but the principle is exactly the same).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to obtain only part of the model you can use a proxy, in this case we create a class that inherits from `QAbstractProxyModel`:

```
class SubProxyModel(QAbstractProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, x, y, nrows, ncols, parent=None):
        QAbstractProxyModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self._x = x
        self._y = y
        self._rows = nrows
        self._cols = ncols

    def setX(self, x):
        self._x = x
        self.modelReset.emit()

    def setY(self, y):
        self._y = y
        self.modelReset.emit()

    def setNRows(self, nrows):
        self._rows = nrows
        self.modelReset.emit()

    def setNCols(self, ncols):
        self._cols = ncols
        self.modelReset.emit()

    def parent(self, child):
        return QModelIndex()

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return self._rows

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return self._cols

    def mapToSource(self, proxyIndex):
        r = proxyIndex.row()
        c = proxyIndex.column()

        nr = r + self._x
        nc = c + self._y
        return self.sourceModel().index(nr, nc)

    def mapFromSource(self, sourceIndex):
        ix = QModelIndex()
        if sourceIndex.isValid():
            r = sourceIndex.row()
            c = sourceIndex.column()
            nr = r - self._x
            nc = c - self._y
            ix = self.index(nr, nc)
        return ix

    def index(self, row, column, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return self.createIndex(row, column)
```

Example:

```
class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        xoffset, yoffset, nRows, nCols = 3, 4, 5, 6

        self.xSpinBox = QSpinBox()
        self.rowsSpinBox = QSpinBox()

        self.ySpinBox = QSpinBox()
        self.colsSpinBox = QSpinBox()

        glay = QGridLayout()

        glay.addWidget(QLabel("x offset:"), 0, 0)
        glay.addWidget(self.xSpinBox, 0, 1)
        glay.addWidget(QLabel("number of rows:"), 0, 2)
        glay.addWidget(self.rowsSpinBox, 0, 3)

        glay.addWidget(QLabel("y offset:"), 1, 0)
        glay.addWidget(self.ySpinBox, 1, 1)
        glay.addWidget(QLabel("number of cols:"), 1, 2)
        glay.addWidget(self.colsSpinBox, 1, 3)

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addLayout(glay)

        self.table = QTableView()
        model = QStandardItemModel(1000, 1000)

        for i in range(model.rowCount()):
            for j in range(model.columnCount()):
                model.setItem(i, j, QStandardItem(f"{i}{j}"))

        proxy = SubProxyModel(xoffset, yoffset, nRows, nCols)

        self.xSpinBox.setValue(xoffset)
        self.ySpinBox.setValue(yoffset)
        self.rowsSpinBox.setValue(nRows)
        self.colsSpinBox.setValue(nCols)

        proxy.setSourceModel(model)
        self.table.setModel(proxy)
        lay.addWidget(self.table)

        self.xSpinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.onXValueChanged)
        self.ySpinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.onYValueChanged)
        self.rowsSpinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.onRowsValueChanged)
        self.colsSpinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.onColsValueChanged)

        self.xSpinBox.setMaximum(model.rowCount() - 1)
        self.ySpinBox.setMaximum(model.columnCount() - 1)

    def onRowsValueChanged(self, value):
        self.table.model().setNRows(value)

    def onColsValueChanged(self, value):
        self.table.model().setNCols(value)

    def onXValueChanged(self, value):
        self.rowsSpinBox.setMaximum(self.table.model().sourceModel().rowCount() - value)
        self.table.model().setX(value)

    def onYValueChanged(self, value):
        self.colsSpinBox.setMaximum(self.table.model().sourceModel().columnCount() - value)
        self.table.model().setY(value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

in the following [link](https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/9d548816ea96c899c3d6c87a5b185d2d) you can find the complete example: