# Add items to a QListWidget, without UI freezing?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm having a little trouble adding a large number of items to a QListWidget without the UI freezing up momentarily. Here's what I have so far:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class Worker(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        for i in range(25000):
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('ping(QString)'), str(i))


class ListDemo(QtGui.QListWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ListDemo, self).__init__()

    def addToList(self, item):
        self.insertItem(0, str(item))
        #app.processEvents()


class Demo(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Demo, self).__init__()
        self.setupUI()

    def setupUI(self):
        self.resize(434, 334)
        self.setWindowTitle('Tester')
        self.mainlayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.listwidget = ListDemo()
        self.mainlayout.addWidget(self.listwidget)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('P O P U L A T E    L I S T')
        self.mainlayout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.populate)

    def populate(self):
        self.listwidget.clear()
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.connect(self.worker, QtCore.SIGNAL("ping(QString)"), self.listwidget.addToList)
        self.worker.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = Demo()
    sys.exit(myapp.exec_())
```

If I enable `app.processEvents()`, python crashes. If I leave it out, the UI seems to wait for the thread to finish before it updates.

What I would like is for the UI to update each time an item is added. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Using a thread in this context will do nothing to stop the gui freezing. In fact, even if it worked, it would probably make things even slower. There is simply no way to add very large numbers of items to a list-widget efficiently *in a single step*. You need to take a completely different approach. One of the most common solutions is to populate the list in batches as the list-widget is scrolled. Another is to use a list-view with a custom model. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39081852/984421)).

Comment: Thanks for the link @ekhumoro. A custom model definitely seems to be the most efficient approach, but to be clear, I'm not wanting to add the items in a single step. My example is an extremely simplified version of a much bigger script that I'm working on, and the list I'm populating could take a little while to fill, so I would like each item to be drawn as it's populated, giving the impression that the UI is functioning, rather than freezing up.

Comment: In that case, your question is completely unclear and misleading. The first sentence refers to "adding a large number of items to a QListWidget", and the code example is attempting to do exactly that. i suggest you re-write the question with your real requirements and provide a much more relevant code example.

Comment: I'm still trying to add a large number of items to a QListWidget - or QListView... I just don't want to do it in a single step. I thought my closing statement basically covered that. Is my example so far removed from what I want to achieve?

Comment: You're just playing semantic games now. Obviously the items have to be added one by one, no matter what approach you take. It's a question of how many items are added in each batch (as I already suggested in my first comment). Your current code tries to dump a continuous stream of 25000 items - and even worse, it also attempts to force a separate gui update *for every single one of those items*. The worker thread is actually doing nothing useful whatsoever, and all the time-consuming work is still being done inside the main thread (only in a horrendously inefficient way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's slower to run, but the UI refreshes regularly and doesn't appear to hang. There may be better solutions out there, but for now, this seems to be doing the trick.

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Worker(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        batch = []
        for i in range(25000):
            batch.append(str(i))
            if len(batch) >= 100: # update UI in batches
                time.sleep(0.005) # small time to rest
                self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('ping(PyQt_PyObject)'), batch)
                batch = []

        # leftovers
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('ping(PyQt_PyObject)'), batch)


class MyList(QtGui.QListWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyList, self).__init__()
        self.setUniformItemSizes(True) #reduces overhead in main thread

    def addToList(self, batch):
        self.insertItems(0, batch[::-1])


class MyWindow(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUI()

    def setupUI(self):
        self.resize(434, 334)
        self.setWindowTitle('Tester')
        self.mainlayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.listwidget = MyList()
        self.mainlayout.addWidget(self.listwidget)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('P O P U L A T E    L I S T')
        self.mainlayout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.populate)

    def populate(self):
        self.listwidget.clear()
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.connect(self.worker, QtCore.SIGNAL("ping(PyQt_PyObject)"), self.listwidget.addToList)
        self.worker.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWindow()
    sys.exit(myapp.exec_())
```